# Browser Downloading Files from Only One Directory

Tags: php, xampp

I've seen a bunch of posts on various sites about browsers trying to download web pages. I have the problem, but with only one directory. I have several websites in my htdocs, each in separate directories. All work fine except one. Each has an index.php file. If I rename and copy the problem index.php to another directory, the browser renders it. The files permissions are the same for the working and non-working directories: 700. It worked fine on my previous Mac Mini and I thought I had it working at one time on the current one. When I do save the file, it still contains the php code so Apache is not executing it, which is why the browser is trying to save it.

XAMPP on OS X 10.8.2

UPDATE

I think I got it to work. I created a new directory in htdocs and copied the contents of the problem directory to it. I renamed the problem directory to something else and renamed the new one to name of the problem directory. Now it works fine. It must be something wrong with the directory. Here's a ls -l for htdocs:

```
drwx------  41 myid  staff    1394 Mar  4 11:23 AmColAn
drwxr-xr-x  29 myid  staff     986 Mar  4 13:06 zetcho
drwxr--r--  30 myid  staff    1020 Mar  4 11:22 zetchoOld
```

The first and second directories work fine. The third one is the problem. Is there some other setting I need to check? I good for now, but I'd like to know in case it happens again.

Comment: Are you accessing the site via `http://localhost/...` or `file:///....` ?

Comment: I'm using localhost and also virtural hosts.

Comment: I mean: What did you type into the browser address bar?